# How to restore or recreate Approve/Reject view (mod-view.aspx)?

Tags: list-view, content-approval

We are using SP2013 on-premise. On a site collection we have some lists with Content Approval enabled. The system automatically add "Approve/Reject" view into the lists. This view is special because only users with "Approval" permission can see it in view selection.

One day our end-user have deleted this view. The list have a lot of production data and we want to avoid re-create the list. Can I restore or re-create Approve/Reject view? I can re-create a new view with the same name and columns but I cannot setup permission and limit it for Approvers only.

Comment: Have you checked the site and site collection recycle bins? Check them while logged in as a site collection admin (farm admin is not necessarily site collection admin in my experience). Do you have any idea how the view was originally being hidden to non-Approvers? I'm quite sure this is not possible out-of-box.

Comment: I checked 2 levels recycle bin with site collection admin and I cannot see it. The end-user deleted the view by UI not by SPD.

Comment: You can reproduce by create a custom list. Then enable the content approval. It will auto create some views including "Approve/Reject" and "My submission". Then login as a viewer and browse the list, you will not see  "Approve/Reject" (but you can see My submission)

Comment: Have you tried recreating the "Approve/Reject" view? If you were able to create it with this same name then that indicates the deleted view is no longer in your recycle bin and won't be recoverable via that method. The only workaround I can think of is you create a new view, edit the web part on the page and select the appropriate security group under the Target Audiences field. This will hide the web part on the page but will not hide the view to those who are not in this group.

Comment: I cannot re-create "Approve/Reject" view because (a) the "Approval status" is a hidden field and I cannot pick it (b) the view have special permission. By checking the code I see ModerationType="Moderator" . I think I need to code it out